# Projections onto subspace - least square method

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been trying to understand projections onto subspace. I *kind of* get it now but there's one thing I can't really wrap my head around. One formula I see is $x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$ which I understand basically is least square. I know that the least square method is used to minimise the distance between b and Ax. **However**, what distance am I actually trying to minimise here. What is X in that formula? And how does it relate to projection? If I'm correct, A is basically the basis of the subspace I'm projecting on, right?

To conclude, what do I actually get when using least square for projection onto subspace and when do I want to use it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you see that $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T=A^{-1}$?

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I see now that I kind of tried to ask two questions at the same time so I removed everything but the least square part. Don't get that and how it related to projections onto subspace.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Yeah, at least when you pointed it out. Don't see how it really relates here though and what it gives me.

Comment: I think for your problem A is not a square matrix in general

Comment: How do you define a projection onto a subspace ?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. 
Let $\mathbf{C}(X)$ denote the column space of $X$ and $\mathbf{C}(X)^\perp$ be its orthogonal complete. Consider a least squares optimization problem $$\min_{P}\lVert y-P_{\mathbf{C}(X)}(y)\rVert_2^2$$

The "error" is the discrepancy between $y$ and $P_{\mathbf{C}(X)}(y)$, which is the distance we are trying to minimize.

Then (in OLS) $$P_{\mathbf{C}(X)} =  X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T $$  will provide the smallest error.

$y$ can be broken into two parts

$$y = \hat{y} +\hat{\epsilon} = P_{\mathbf{C}(X)}(y)+P_{\mathbf{C}(X)^\perp}(y)$$

This can be seen in this visualization
[image]

This can also be written as

$$\min_{\beta}\lVert y-X\beta\rVert_2^2$$

where the optimal solution is $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$,
This is why you see this formula frequently in relation to minimizing distance. In particular, the specific relation between the projection and $\hat{\beta}$ is

$$P_{\mathbf{C}(X)}(y) =  X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T y = X \hat{\beta}$$